# Creating Test script for login django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

Please help me. I am currently tasked to create a test script for the login method.

This is the login method that I am testing...

```
    class AuthViewModel():
        fixture = [user]
        user_name = 'usera'
        password = '12345678'

        def login_page(self, userName, password, request):
            """
            Login by ID & PWD
            """

            # Get user by name & password
            self.user = authenticate(username=userName, password=password)

            if self.user is not None:
                if self.user.is_active:
                    # Login by Django
                    login(request, self.user)
                else:
                    # User not active
                    self.message = "User is not actived yet"
            else:
                # User not exist
                self.message = "User name or password is incorrect"
```

And this is the test script that I did.

```
def test_login_page(self):
    """Test log in
    """

    actauth = AuthViewModel()
    actauth.actinbox_login(self.user_name, self.password, request)
    self.assertEqual(actauth.message, 'User name or password is incorrect')
```

This is my problem, I received error message

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

how to define 'request' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a request object with a [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory).

> The RequestFactory shares the same API as the test client. However,
>   instead of behaving like a browser, the RequestFactory provides a way
>   to generate a request instance that can be used as the first argument
>   to any view. This means you can test a view function the same way as
>   you would test any other function – as a black box, with exactly known
>   inputs, testing for specific outputs.

So basically

```
 factory = RequestFactory()
 request = factory.get('/your/login/page/')
 actauth = AuthViewModel()
 actauth.actinbox_login(self.user_name, self.password, request)
 self.assertEqual(actauth.message, 'User name or password is incorrect')
```

Comment: Glad to have been of some use. Might I also humbly suggest that the answer be marked as correct. Might be usefull for someone who lands here in the future and we both get useless internet points :-)

Comment: Yes I will. :) I really want to be a better programmer like you and I could also help others as well.

Comment: Oh, I am pretty sure you are pretty good programmer yourself. Experience you will naturally gain over time.